# java random number chooser

Tags: java

I have a homework to write a method that returns a random number between
1 and 54, excluding the numbers passed in the argument. The method header is
specified as follows:

```
public static int getRandom(int... numbers)
```

I can't use anything more advanced than Single-Dimensional Arrays.

my code is:

```
public class PE13RandomNumberChooserVer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] excludeNumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
        int randomNumber = getRandom(excludeNumbers);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Random number chosen: " + randomNumber);
    }

    public static int getRandom(int... excludeNumbers) {

        int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (54 - 1) + 1);
        System.out.println("Numbers to exclude: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < excludeNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(excludeNumbers[i] + " ");
            while (excludeNumbers[i] == random) {
                random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
                System.out.println("\n(for test only) next random number: " + random);
            }
        }

        return random;
    }

}
```

a sample run showed that my logic is wrong:

```
(for test only) initial random number: 8
Numbers to exclude: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
(for test only) next random number: 12
11 12 
(for test only) next random number: 3
13 14 15 16 17 18 
Random number chosen: 3
```

it checks only if random is equal to the current item in the array, it doesn't consider the case in which it can be equal to the previous item in the list that is already checked.

The end result for the random generated number should be a value different from the numbers in the array.
Any suggestions how to fix it are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u please mention example with desired output as well?

Comment: I don't see how your sample output matches the messages printed in the code?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Generate a random number, check if it's in the `excludeNumbers` array. If it is, rerun `getRandom()`, otherwise, return the generated number.

Comment: I think it would be better to have a list of numbers, 1 through 54. Come up with a new list excluding the numbers passed in as arguments. And use the random as the index, which could vary from 0 through the size of the new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    public int getRandom(int min, int max, int... excludeNumbers) {
        int random = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1 - excludeNumbers.length) + min;
        for (int exc : excludeNumbers) {
            if (random >= exc) {
                random++;
            }
        }
        return random;
    }
```

Observe how it only generates a single random number and doesn't require a rejection loop.

Note that both `min` and `max` are inclusive. Also note that `excludeNumbers` must appear in ascending order.

Comment: I've tested your code and it is working with as it should, but how to the same range (and result) with simple 
`int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);` 
random generator, because I'm not able to use Random class.
Could you please clarify what is actually the for each loop does in this case, thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (54 - 1) + 1);
```

and this

```
random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
```

are strange and should coincide.

Latter one is correct.

Next your loops are wrong. Loops are for regenerating number in case it coincides with prohibited one. So you should place `for` inside `while` and place `println` outside all loops. `for` should serve to check all prohibited numbers for one generated and `while` should server as retriement loop.

Also you can use [Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

**THE CODE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] excludeNumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
        int randomNumber;

        System.out.println("Numbers to exclude: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < excludeNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(excludeNumbers[i] + " ");
        }


        // 100 tests
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i ) {


            randomNumber = getRandom(excludeNumbers);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Random number chosen: " + randomNumber);
        }
    }

    public static int getRandom(int... excludeNumbers) {

        int random;



        // regeneration loop 
        regeneration: while(true) {

            // generating a number
            random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);

            // checking of it's correctness
            for (int i = 0; i < excludeNumbers.length; i++) {

                // checking if number conincides for prohibited
                if( excludeNumbers[i] == random ) {

                    // if number concided, then going to regeneration
                    continue regeneration;
                }

                // here number has not coincided 
                // but with just one of prohibites
                // no decision here
            }

            // here all prohibited numbers checked and 
            // no coincidences found
            // so generated number is good

            System.out.println("\n(for test only) next random number: " + random);
            break regeneration;

        } 

        return random;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, what is `regeneration:` and how to look for it in the java's documentation?

Comment: It is labelled statement (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7). It is not required here actually. You can get out of the loop as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which simply keeps trying until you get an acceptable number.

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(excludedNumbers);
while (true) {
    Random random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
    if (!nums.contains(random))
        return random;
}
```

The method would be cleaner if you passed exclude numbers as a list.

Answer (score 1):

The techniques that keep retrying until hitting an allowed number are crude and turn into a crying misery as the number of allowed numbers approaches 1. A much more elegant way is this:

1. create a `boolean[54]`;
2. set each excluded element to `true`;
3. choose a random number *r* from a range as large as the number of allowed choices (54 - number of exclusions);
4. return the *rth* false element in the boolean array.

Note: this algorithm is the best fit when you can cache the `boolean` array; for your exact case (the function receives a new array every time) NPE's solution is superior.

Comment: Have troubles with 3 and 4 steps, if everything is ok, though `public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] exc = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11};
  int random = getRandom(exc);
  System.out.println("choosen is " + random);
 }
 
 public static int getRandom(int... numbers) {
  boolean[] boolNums = new boolean[54];
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   boolNums[numbers[i]] = true;
  }
  int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (54 - numbers.length));
  // return rth false element
  return random;
 }`
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Look into java.util.random, it has a method that provides a random integer between 0 and your specified number. I can't give you an example because I'm typing this from my phone at the moment, but if you were to get it between 1 and 54 I would get a random number between 0 and 53 and add 1 to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am also teaching myself Java right now. I spend several days on this problem already while there is no answer available yet online. The solution above is too advanced for me so far. Here is my solution finally, which employ basic array knowledge only

```
    public class Q6_13 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int[] excludeNumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
        System.out.println (getRandom(excludeNumbers));
    }

    public static int getRandom(int...numbers)  {
        int n =  (int)(Math.random() * 54) + 1; ;
        boolean newRandom = false;
        boolean getNew = false;

         while (getNew == false)   {
        for (int i = 0; (i < numbers.length) && newRandom == false; i++)    {
            if (n == numbers[i])    {
                newRandom = true;                 
            }
        }
            if (newRandom)  {
                n = (int)(Math.random() * 54) + 1; 
                getNew = false;
                newRandom = false;
            }
            else
                getNew = true;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getRandom(int... numbers) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int[] arr1 = new int[54];
    int count = 54;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        arr1[i] = i + 1; // good luck doing this with foreach
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
        final int n = numbers[i];
        if(arr1[n] != 0) {
            --count;
        }
        arr1[n] = 0;
    }
    final int[] arr2 = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i, ++j) {
        if(arr1[j] == 0) {
            ++j;
        }
        else {
            arr2[i] = arr1[j];
        }
    }
    return arr2[random.nextInt(count)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Compute {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41};
    int x = 1+ (int) (Math.random()*54);
    System.out.println("Value: "+getRandom(x,values));  
}

public static int getRandom(int a, int... numbers){

    System.out.println("x1: "+a);
    for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;){
        //System.out.println("Numbers: "+numbers[j]);
        if(numbers[j]==a){
            a = 1 + (int) (Math.random()*54);
            System.out.println("x2: "+a);
            j=0;
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return a;

}
```

}